# Nuget List CLI command is showing deleted packages

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core-2.0, rider

I am on a Mac using .net core 2.0 and Jetbrains Rider. I have a network folder where I publish my private nuget packages.

```
nuget push <packagePath> -source <localNugetPath>
```

I delete a package from the local folder.

```
nuget delete <packageID> <packageVersion> [options]
```

This deleted the nuget package from the network folder but yet it still shows in Rider as an options.

```
nuget list [search terms] [options]
```

The above nuget list command will also show the package. How do I permanently get ride of the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet does not allow for package delete and instead relies on unlisting the packages. This means:

- This unlisted version is not shown in new searches and hence will not get auto resolved to, in new projects.
- However, existing projects that have references to this unlisted version continue to work as before. (And that's one of the reasons for not allowing delete - so that existing projects do not break)

The package can shows because it cached. To clean all cache use command:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Comment: I tried that and the command showed success but It still shows up in nuget list as well as rider.

Comment: Yes nuget list with the source command still shows the delete package

Comment: So are you saying this is no way to delete it from showing up from the list in the current project even though I does not have a reference anywhere to it and it is delete from the local nuget repository?

Comment: I figured out the issue. The network drive was on a local Synology NAS. That shared folder had the recycle bin option on it. It move the folder to the recycle bin instead of fully deleting the package. Once I removed it form the recycle bin it now longer show up in the list. Thanks for your help you steps worked.